# VB.Net How to close random choosed form

Tags: vb.net, random

I am making some kind of quiz. I have made randomizer for questions. So when one question(form) pops up and when I click the right answer new form pops up, where you have one label and button to continue. I have made that when I click continue button next question(form) pops up, but i want that the previous form closes too, but i dont know how to name it or what to do.

```
Dim rn As New Random 
TextBox1.Text = rn.Next(1, 4) 

If TextBox1.Text = 1 Then
   Form4.Show() 
   Form4.Timer1.Start() 
End If 
If TextBox1.Text = 2 Then 
   Form7.Show() 
   Form7.Timer1.Start() 
End If 

If TextBox1.Text = 3 Then 
     Form8.Show() 
     Form8.Timer1.Start() 
End If 
If TextBox1.Text = 4 Then 
    Form12.Show() 
    Form12.Timer1.Start() 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Hand over a reference to the question to the result form. Then you can call the Close() method on the previous question before opening the next one.

Comment: Add an event handler for the button-click Event and call Close() on the previous form there.

Answer (score 0):

How about a routine that closes all your forms before opening a new one.

This isn't the best way - as your telling the forms to close even if they weren't open.
But it will do what you are asking.

Here is an example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rn As New Random
    Dim randomForm As UInteger = rn.Next(1, 3) 'Random Form Number
    TextBox1.Text = randomForm 'Store the Random Number here

    closeQuestionForms() 'Routine called before opening others

    Select Case randomForm
        Case 1
            Form2.Show()
            'Do something else here
        Case 2
            Form3.Show()
    End Select

End Sub


Private Sub closeQuestionForms() 'Closes the forms
    Form2.Close()
    Form3.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Closed Question Forms")
End Sub
```

Again, There is probably a better way which other answers might show you. But this way should work fine.

Comment: I did something else. So I have always open start menu and then questions. I added checkbox to start menu (make them invisivble) and wrote if codes. To continue button I added: If Form1.CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
            Form4.Close()
        End If

        If Form1.CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
            Form7.Close()
        End If

        If Form1.CheckBox4.Checked = True Then
            Form8.Close()
        End If

        Form1.CheckBox2.Checked = False
        Form1.CheckBox3.Checked = False
        Form1.CheckBox4.Checked = False   But thanks for the help anyway...